# Is is okay to run 4" PVC drain pipe on the outside of a house?

Tags: plumbing, drain, pvc, old-house, winter

I have to run 4" drain pipe for the washer that is on the second floor, but, the building being old and all, I wouldn't want to rip the floors, instead, I was thinking of running the drain on the outside of the house and then go back in at the basement level. It would be preferable as the pipe would be hidden with other exterior pipes and would not look ugly or out of place. This is for state of CT, so to prevent winter freezing, I was told to go with 4" PVC instead of the 3" recommended by washer manual. Any suggestions? Drilling through the floor to run the pipe on the inside is not possible, so, what options do I have?

Thanks.

Comment: PVC does not do well exposed to sunlight. Are you going to tie this into your sewer or septic system?

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest a "Pipe chase" (box, preferably well insulated) around the pipe on the outside of the house in a freezing climate.

That same box will also help to "improve the appearance" (if the pipe will be "grouped with other outside pipes" as you say they can all be in the box, though I'm frankly puzzled as to what such a group of pipes on the exterior would be in a freezing climate...) and protects the PVC pipe from sunlight.

Whether any single measure (such as oversizing the pipe) or combination of measures will actually "protect from freezing" where you expose a pipe to freezing temperatures is highly dependent on the weather for the day or week, the particular details of the water flow in the pipe, and how they interact. If it freezes more than it thaws, it will eventually build up a plug of ice and be a problem - which is why most folks in cold climates try to avoid having plumbing in the outside walls, much less all the way outside the house.

Comment: Note that the chase needs to be a) well-insulated from the outside, and b) NOT insulated from the inside. Otherwise, no matter how much insulation you use, it will eventually freeze.

Comment: You're dumping water that's above freezing (sometimes well above freezing) into it. If it's adequately insulated, that will be sufficient heat to keep it clear without requiring removing insulation on the house side, as it's a vertical pipe.

Comment: What if there's a running faucet or toilet that causes a slow dribble? You'd get this gradual buildup of ice in the pipe, quite likely eventually blocking it. Then how do you unblock it; wait for warm weather?

Comment: Did you **Read the Question?** It's specifically a Clothes-Washer Drain line. High volume, short duration, I've never seen one "dribble" - if it did, you'd have a full washer tub inside the house, not a trickle into the drain line..

Comment: I'd still be concerned. I live at most 90 miles north of the OP, and we've had winters where it stayed in the single digits for days on end. It's a risk call; I wouldn't do it.

Comment: I'm used to -20F for a couple of weeks. Note my answer's last sentence. But Biz Way is clearly not going to take that route, so I'm looking for an answer that's actually of use - and a vertical washer drain-pipe is quite hard to freeze, compared to anything with a trickle being possible.

Answer (score 0):

Most older homes in Europe that were built in the days before indoor plumbing have their sanitary drains on the outside of the house.  I worked in an large industrial complex that did the same (northern New Hampshire). Sometimes a heat trace with thermostat is used.

Comment: Most sanitary drains have warm to hot flows, such as bath, sinks, dishwashers, and washing machines.

Comment: You're right, and in the UK those external waste pipes were normally cast iron too.  OTOH bath/shower water is normally warm or hot, as is dishwasher water, but washing machines are using lower and lower temperatures to save energy.  Mine does pretty well on cold (completely unheated, so no more than about room temp when it's drained away)

Answer (score -1):

Perfectly fine to run outside, much easier for builder, much easier for plumber, very easy to access if problems occur, freezing no problem since in the sewer lots of bacterial activity produces heat. No reason to cover in a box, but must be painted in order to protect from sunlight.